# How to clone a class but not copy mutable attributes?

Tags: python, class, oop, dill

I am trying to write python code that will be able to track the created instances of a class, and save it through sessions. I am trying to to this by creating a list inside the class deceleration, which keeps track of instances. My code is as follows:

```
class test_object:
    _tracking = []

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.name = text
        test_object._tracking.insert(0, self)

with open("tst.pkl", mode="rb") as f:
    try:
        pickles = dill.load(f)
    except:
        pickles = test_object
        logger.warning("Found dill to be empty")
f.close()
```

My issue is handling when the pickled data is empty. What I'd like to do is in this case simply use the base class. The issue I'm running into is that `test_object._tracking` ends up being equal to `pickles._tracking`. Is there a way to make a copy of `test_object` so that when `test_object._tracking` gets updates, `pickles._tracking` stays the same?

Comment: in the 'except' part, you're setting pickles to the class test_object - and not to an instance of the class. Is that the intention? Why? (also, no need to close f, as you're using 'with').

Comment: @Roy2012 yes, the point is to set it to the class. I want to pickle the class, which has a list of its instances. The idea is to pickle and unpickle the class and its instances together in a simple and compact way. The idea here is if nothing is pickled, I want a way to copy the class without having any instances. Since `test_object` hasn't been called yet, its `_tracking` should be empty, so it is a way to set `pickle` to the class without any instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
import dill 

class test_object:
    _tracking = []

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.name = text
        test_object._tracking.insert(0, self)

test_1 = test_object("abc")
print(test_object._tracking)
# result: [<__main__.test_object object at 0x11a8cda50>]

with open("./my_file.txt", mode="rb") as f:
    try:
        pickles = dill.load(f)
    except:
        pickles = type('test_object_copy', test_object.__bases__, dict(test_object.__dict__))
        pickles._tracking = []

        print("Found dill to be empty")
# The above results in "Found dill to be empty"

print(pickles._tracking)
# prints []
```

it'll set pickles to a copy of the original class. It's tracking attribute would then be empty, and would be different than the original 'tracking'.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. I tested it by adding `test_object._tracking.append("test"); print(pickles._tracking)` in the `except` clause, and get an output of `['test']`. I.e. the issue with that approach is that the `pickle` and `test_object` share a `_tracking` list.

Comment: Got it. I thought you want to make sure that the pickle object doesn't change with the class after it's created. I'll change the code to make sure _tracking is empty when it's created.

Comment: It does work, but it's kinda hacky. I wonder if a more general solution is possible. My concern is if I needed my class to track more things, although I think this is good enough for a problem this obscure,

Comment: Yep ... it is kind of hacky - but wait till you see my other solution which combines assembly, COBOL, and some ducktape :)